# Condition in having/where clause in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause, having

So I have a simple query that takes in the following parameters from a report (Company Code and Division Code) and returns a list of all items that are within that company and within that division of said company.

Now I want to have the option to select all division. So instead of choosing company one division one, you could choose company one division all.

So I added a value to my division code properties with NULL as the actual code and 'All' as the name.

My query is long but here is the most important line

```
Having Style.Company_Code = @CompanyCode And Style.Division_Code = @DivisionCode
```

So at the end of the long query, it just selects all the rows with the specified company and division code.

If I change the line to this (removing the division part completely)

```
Having Style.Company_Code = @CompanyCode
```

It works as intended, showing me all items from all division of a specified company, ignoring the division field completely. However, obviously, this removes the functionality of choosing a division.

So I changed the line to this.

```
Having Style.Company_Code = @CompanyCode And (Style.Division_Code = @DivisionCode OR @DivisionCode = NULL)
```

If I select a division, it works as it should, but if I select 'ALL' which has a value of NULL, it just returns nothing. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In SQL, comparisons with `= NULL` rarely make sense. You want `IS NULL`.

Comment: Check https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-%E2%80%9Cis-null%E2%80%9D-and-%E2%80%9C-null%E2%80%9D-in-SQL for a detailed explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is on the way that logic behind NULLS.
Condition NULL = NULL is evaluated as FALSE
In my proposal you ask: NULL IS NULL and this is TRUE
Please, try as below:

```
HAVING Style.Company_Code = @CompanyCode 
  AND (Style.Division_Code = @DivisionCode OR @DivisionCode IS NULL)
```

Comment: Yep that was it! Thank you!

Comment: @Natan SO works best when you mark the response as an answer if it does, in fact, answer your question. That is how people with similar questions find **answers**.